# Handle Next and Done Button in Custom KeyBoard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

How to handle Next and Done button at a time in custom keyboard as like android default keyboard. If i have two EditText in my screen

Below is the code which i am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:horizontalGap="0dp"
    android:keyHeight="54dp"
    android:keyWidth="25%p"
    android:verticalGap="0dp" >

    <Row>
        <Key
            android:codes="8"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
            android:keyLabel="1" />
        <Key
            android:codes="9"
            android:keyLabel="2" />
        <Key
            android:codes="10"
            android:keyLabel="3" />
        <Key
            android:codes="69"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyLabel="-" />
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key
            android:codes="11"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
            android:keyLabel="4" />
        <Key
            android:codes="12"
            android:keyLabel="5" />
        <Key
            android:codes="13"
            android:keyLabel="6" />
        <Key
            android:codes="56"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyLabel="." />
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key
            android:codes="14"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
            android:keyLabel="7" />
        <Key
            android:codes="15"
            android:keyLabel="8" />
        <Key
            android:codes="16"
            android:keyLabel="9" />
        <Key
            android:codes="67"
            android:iconPreview="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete" />
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key
            android:codes="7"
            android:keyLabel="0"
            android:keyWidth="50%p" />
        <Key
            android:codes="66"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyLabel="Done"
            android:keyWidth="50%p" />
    </Row>

</Keyboard>
```

and then Coming to java code

```
public CustomKeyboardView mKeyboardView;
    private Keyboard mKeyboard;

    private void setCustomKeyBoard(){

        mKeyboard = new Keyboard(mContext, R.xml.keyboard);

        mKeyboardView = (CustomKeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboard_view);
        mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false);
        mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(mKeyboard);
        mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(new BasicOnKeyboardActionListener(this));
    }
```

and in Manifest i have declared as

```
<activity
            android:name="com.app.CommonActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not set both bottom, you shold first disable next button and replace to set on done botton

#### EditText (.java)

`etname.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);`

Full Code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText etname;

    etname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    etname.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

   }
}
```

---

#### EditText (.xml)

`android:imeOptions="actionDone"`

Full Code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etname"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone" >
</EditText>
```

Comment: oky oky, i found this URL may be very good, you check may be help you - http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm